# If azure VM is idle for 30 minutes I need to shut it down

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-vm-role

If an azure VM is idle for 30 minutes I need to shut it down. By idle I mean CPU percent is less than 30%. How can I achieve this?

I have tried with run books default functions but it has shutdown and start but not with idle time.

Comment: And what is your definition of idle time?

Comment: if cpu percent is less than 30%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by Powershell , you can run this command as a scheduled job based on your requirement :

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -Name <your vm name> -ResourceGroupName <your resource group name>
$current = Get-Date

#get cpuMetrics for each minute in past 30 mins 
$cpuMetrics = Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $vm.Id -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -StartTime $current.AddMinutes(-30) -EndTime $current -DetailedOutput -MetricNames "Percentage CPU"
$CPUUsangeRange = ($cpuMetrics.Data | select Average).Average | measure -Maximum

#get Maximum value of cpu usage percentage in past 30 mins, if the Maximum value less than 30% ,its idle and stop it .
if($CPUUsangeRange.Maximum -lt 30){
   Stop-AzureRMvm -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Force
}
```

Sometimes you cannot get last 2 or 3 mins cpu Metrics data as there will be some latency.

Comment: Get-AzureRmMetric : The term 'Get-AzureRmMetric' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:28 char:15
+ $cpuMetrics = Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $vm.Id -TimeGrain 00:01:0 ...
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureRmMetric:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Hi @user12395612 , could you pls have a check that have you installed AzureRM.Insights module ?

Comment: Hi @user12395612 , there is no such command : Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition in my script . I am not sure why you will get this error . Btw , the AzureRM.Insights module version is 5.1.5 . I have tested this script on my side and it did work for me.

Comment: what is for Timegrain used

Comment: i have checked and installed azurerm.insights. now its working

Comment: Hi @user12395612 Timegrain is the unit of metrics , in my case is 00:01:00 which means to get each minute average CPU usage. Glad to know that  it works for you . If it is helpful , pls mark this as an answer and I am glad to answer your further questions , thanks !

Comment: Is there anything like Get-AzureRmMetric command will work only if insights is enabled in vm..

Comment: Hi @user12395612 , it is based on what metrics that you want to monitor. Different kind of resources have different metrics . By default , for Azure VMs,  the following metrics is enabled without additional configuration : CPU usage, network usage, total of disk bytes, and disk operations per second. You can see these metrics on Azure portal too.